# How to test if there's a statistically significant difference between two counts, based on relative percentile?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

How to test if there's a statistically significant difference between two counts
Hi! I'm struggling to test if two ratios on the same row of my dataset are significantly different from each other. I need to do this test for as many rows are in my dataset. The ratios, a and b, are in two separate columns of my data, and I'm trying only to plot points that have a statistically significant difference between them.

What I've done is take the difference between each set of values (a - b) and calculated the percentile rank of each difference relative to its column using scipy.stats.percentileofscore. I've made a histogram of this data. But I'm not sure how to proceed now. The histogram doesn't look normal. I want to just take the values above 95 and below 5 percent on the histogram, but since my distribution isn't normal I don't think that'd be correct!

What's difficult here is that I'm analyzing data from an experiment I really should have done in replicates, rather than just once. And comparing between counts, not averages, confuses me.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You say you want to compare two ratios, a and b, to determine if they're significantly different. How are counts involved? Do you know the actual counts underlying the ratios? Can you say more about what they represent?

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much. My rows are different DNA sequences. My columns are the DNA sequencing reads which a single sequence got in two different experimental scenarios. So the two numbers are - how many DNA sequencing reads did we see in scenario A, versus how many sequencing reads did we see in scenario B, for the same DNA sequence. The sum of the column values gives the total number of sequencing reads across experiment A.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple test of proportions. Basically, you'd like to see if DNA reads appear at different *rates* between sample types, knowing that the sample types may have different numbers of total reads.

To do this, you can run a chi-squared or Fisher test on a 2x2 contingency table - on one axis you have "Condition 1" and "Condition 2", and on the other, you have  "Read in Gene" versus "Read Not in Gene". For every query gene, fill in the table counting the number of reads you saw for each gene in each condition, as well as the remaining number of reads that didn't get assigned to that gene for each condition. The chi squared or Fisher test will tell you if a different *proportion* of reads get assigned to the gene between the two conditions.

As perhaps a simpler analogy for this problem, it's the same as rolling two dice many times, and try to determine if any of the numbers appear at significantly different rates.